# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'T-100-060' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran this query and I got the error in the title.  I'm trying to find out if the partnumber exits in the products.specifications table the partnumber is defined as a integer in products.specifications

```
Select  products.Specifications.ProductID
FROM    Products.Products
JOIN    Products.Specifications
ON      Products.Products.PartNumber = Products.Specifications.ProductID
where ProductTypeID = '15'
```

Please help thanks

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Why don't you just check PartNumber and ProductID for the value you're getting an error on. You should get in the practice of using aliases.

Comment: It is trivially obvious that the string value `T-100-060` cannot be converted to an integer--integers are whole numbers, and whole numbers don't contain letters or dashes. If `ProductID` *is* an integer, then it is not the same kind of thing as `PartNumber`. Your database isn't constructed the way you think it is. You can't join `PartNumber` to `ProductID` any more than you can do `A JOIN B ON 'Apple' = 23`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could cast the number to a string:

```
Select  products.Specifications.ProductID
FROM    Products.Products
JOIN    Products.Specifications
ON      Products.Products.PartNumber = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Products.Specifications.ProductID)
where ProductTypeID = '15'
```

But then you need to determine if there are any edge cases to be concerned about - whitespace, leading zeros, etc.

> I'm trying to find out if the partnumber exits in the products.specifications table

Then you should use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products.Products
WHERE PartNumber IN
(
   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ProductID)
   FROM Products.Specifications
)
AND ProductTypeID = '15'
```

a `JOIN` will give you mutliple results if `partnumber` matches multiple records in `products.specifications`.

Comment: If there's an index on `Products.Products.PartNumber` it shouldn't be bad.  You could also add an index on the string conversion to improve performance. Obviously would be best if the two were the same type.

Comment: The fact that you are joinging on a scalar converted column will degrade the performance quite substantially.

Comment: Not if there's an index on that scalar conversion.